# Generic method with Action<T> parameter

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

So, I'm sure this has been answered somewhere out there before, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Hoping some generics guru can help.

```
public interface IAnimal{}
public class Orangutan:IAnimal{}

public void ValidateUsing<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IAnimal
{
    Orangutan orangutan = new Orangutan();
    action(orangutan);  //Compile error 1

    //This doesn't work either:
    IAnimal animal = new Orangutan();
    action(animal);  //Compile error 2
}
```

1. Argument type 'Orangutan' is not assignable to parameter type 'T'
2. Argument type 'IAnimal' is not assignable to parameter type 'T'

**Edit: Based on Yuriy and other's suggestions**, I could do some casting such as:

```
public void ValidateUsing<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IAnimal
{
    Orangutan orangutan = new Orangutan();
    action((T)(IAnimal)orangutan);

    //This doesn't work either:
    IAnimal animal = new Orangutan();
    action((T)animal);
}
```

The thing I wanted to do was call the ValidateUsing method like this:

```
ValidateUsing(Foo);
```

Unfortunately, if foo looks like this:

```
private void Foo(Orangutan obj)
{
    //Do something
}
```

I have to explicitly specify the type when I call ValidateUsing

```
ValidateUsing<Orangutan>(Foo);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you instantiating an `Orangutan` if you are supposed to be accepting any `IAnimal`?

```
public void ValidateUsing<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IAnimal, new()
{
    T animal = new T();
    action(animal);  //Compile error 2
```

If you reuse your generic parameter, you won't have any type issues...

Now, with regard to why your code doesn't work, all that you're saying is that the type `T` will derive from `IAnimal`.  However, it could just as easily be a `Giraffe` as an `Orangutan`, so you can't just assign an `Orangutan` or `IAnimal` to a parameter of type `T`.

Comment: Thanks bdukes, I just used Orangutan as an example. Probably a bad one. I want to be able to call the action with any IAnimal. In the "real" code, the IAnimal is stored as a private field in the class. So, I'm not really instantiating anything.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, that T represents **some** type which by the way implements IAnimal.

So, when you try to compile `action(new Organatum())` you getting an error because you have declared that the action should take a parameter of type `T` which in its turn could be of type, let's say, `Fish` - you can't cast `Organatum` to a `Fish`, can you?

If you want to trigger any action which takes parameter of a type which implements `IAnimal` interface, then simply forget about generics and use `Action<IAnimal>`.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Orangutan orangutan = new Orangutan();
Action<IAnimal> castedAction = action as Action<IAnimal>;
castedAction(orangutan);
```

Comment: Thanks Stan! I'd upvote your answer if I had enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Make the following changes:

```
Orangutan orangutan = new Orangutan();
action((T)(IAnimal)orangutan); 


IAnimal animal = new Orangutan();
action((T)animal);
```

Comment: Hi Yuriy, this works very well.  It's gets me part of the way (see edit). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IAnimal { }
public class Orangutan : IAnimal { }

public void ValidateUsing<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IAnimal
{
    Orangutan orangutan = new Orangutan();
    action((T)(orangutan as IAnimal));  // needs to be cast as IAnimal

    //This doesn't work either:
    IAnimal animal = new Orangutan();
    action((T)animal);  // needs to be cast as T
}
```

It also seems like the fact that it's an interface makes a difference.  If you had an abstract class Animal, instead of an interface, you could do this:

```
public abstract class Animal { }
public class Orangutan : Animal { }

public void ValidateUsing<T>(Action<T> action) where T : Animal
{
    Orangutan orangutan = new Orangutan();
    action(orangutan as T); 

    //This doesn't work either:
    Animal animal = new Orangutan();
    action(animal as T); 
}
```

Comment: Hi climbage, thanks for the detailed answer. I tend to use interfaces much more often than abstract classes (favor composition vs. inheritance and all that), but it's interesting to know that it works with an abstract class.