# How to pass a Subroutine name as an argument for a function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, methods, arguments, argument-passing

I'm trying to make a generic Function to create threads, then I need to pass a Subroutine name to the function, but I could only pass a Function name (which is useless).

How I can do this?

There is a way to do it without declaring the delegate out of the function? ...'cause like I said I'll make a generic function to simplify the things.

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

' Desired usage:
' Make_Thread(Thread Variable, Thread Name, Thread Priority, Thread Sub)
'
' Example:
' Make_Thread(Thread_1, "Low thread", Threading.ThreadPriority.Low, AddressOf Test_Sub)

Private Thread_1 As Threading.Thread ' Thread Variable

Private Function Make_Thread(Of TKey)(ByRef Thread_Variable As Threading.Thread, _
                       ByVal Thread_Name As String, _
                       ByVal Thread_Priority As Threading.ThreadPriority, _
                       ByRef Thread_Sub As Func(Of String, TKey)) As Boolean ' I'd ByRef a function but really I will pass a Subroutine.

    ' See if the thread is already running.
    Dim is_running As Boolean
    If Thread_Variable Is Nothing Then _
         is_running = False _
    Else is_running = Thread_Variable.IsAlive

    ' If the thread is already running, do nothing.
    If is_running Then Return False : Exit Function

    ' Make the thread.
    Thread_Variable = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Thread_Sub)
    Thread_Variable.Priority = Thread_Priority
    Thread_Variable.IsBackground = True
    Thread_Variable.Name = Thread_Name

    ' Start the thread.
    Thread_Variable.Start()
    Return True

End Function

Private Sub Test_Sub()
    MsgBox("A message from the thread!")
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792101/generic-method-with-actiont-parameter

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the info. Well is a little hard for me to understand C# syntax and to understand what the user is trying in that example, I'm not sure if that is what I need but I think not 'cause he is trying to pass an interface?, I'm trying to pass a method name (a procedure, a sub, a typically sub for a new thread) to assign the Sub as a thread Sub in this part of the code : `Thread_Variable = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Subroutine_Name)`.

Comment: You would probably find it much easier to use the Task library rather than re-inventing the wheel and manually creating threads.  You would just call:  `Dim myTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf SomeSub)`